# GUI for choosing different sorting in python by Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am using this code for radio buttons:

```
  v= IntVar()

  self.button1 = Radiobutton( self, text = "Bubble Sort" ,variable=v,value=1)
  self.button1.grid( row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W+E+N+S )


  self.button2 = Radiobutton( self, text = "Quick Sort",variable=v,value=2)
  self.button2.grid( row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W+E+N+S )


  self.button3 = Radiobutton( self, text = "Shell Sort", variable=v,value=3)
  self.button3.grid( row = 1, column = 2, sticky = W+E+N+S )
```

For more reference the full code is above and screen shot is like this:

[image]

How do I do sorting on these numbers by clicking button after selecting the sort? Do I first have to select the sort from three given and then click button sort to sort the numbers?

Here is the rest:

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
class Sorting( Frame ):
  def __init__( self ):
   Frame.__init__( self )
   self.master.title( "Sorting" )

   self.master.rowconfigure( 5, weight = 1 )
   self.master.columnconfigure( 5, weight = 1 )
   self.grid( sticky = W+E+N+S )
   #label for sort intro

   self.label1 = Label( self, text = "Select Sort", width = 25 ,height=2)
   self.label1.grid( row = 0, column = 1, sticky = N )



   #Radio buttons for sorts
   v= IntVar()

   self.button1 = Radiobutton( self, text = "Bubble Sort" ,variable=v,value=1)
   self.button1.grid( row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W+E+N+S )


   self.button2 = Radiobutton( self, text = "Quick Sort",variable=v,value=2)
   self.button2.grid( row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W+E+N+S )


   self.button3 = Radiobutton( self, text = "Shell Sort", variable=v,value=3)
   self.button3.grid( row = 1, column = 2, sticky = W+E+N+S )

 #function to do soting
   #def sort():

 #label to store value
   def gen():
    self.nums = []
    for x in range(0, 10):
       self.nums.append(random.randint(0, 100))
  # . . . . . . . . . .  .    <- maybe here call sorting method on self.nums


       num = ''.join('%4i' % num for num in self.nums)
       self.label2 = Label( self, text=num, width=2, height=2)
       self.label2.grid(row=3, columnspan=10, sticky=W+E+N+S)

         #self.label2.pack(fill="both")

     #Button for sorting
   self.button5=Button(self,text='start sorting')
   self.button5.grid( row = 4,column=1, sticky = W+E+N+S )

   #button to generate number
   self.button4 = Button( self,text='Generate no.',command=gen )
   self.button4.grid( row = 2,column=1, sticky = W+E+N+S )
   self.rowconfigure( 1, weight = 1 )
   self.columnconfigure( 1, weight = 1 )
def main():
  Sorting().mainloop()   

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: No, the ***full code*** you post **did not** generated your image. Where the "start sorting" button is defined ?, why the buttons1-3 are defined differently than in the first code segment of your post ?

Comment: sorry i posted the code by mistake the old one

Comment: sorry for inconvenience. i have corrected the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement a callback method for your `start sorting` button:

```
  def sortit(self):
        function = self.function[self.v.get()]
        result = function()
        num = ''.join('%4i' % num for num in result)
        self.label3 = Label(self, text=num, width=2, height=2)
        self.label3.grid(row=5, columnspan=10, sticky=W+E+N+S )
```

There you get the button pressed in `self.v.get()`.
This integer value is used as a key for a dictionary that stores your sorting method names:

```
 self.function = {0:self.bubble, 1:self.quick, 2:self.shell}
```

then `result = function()` gives you the result of calling the corresponding sorting method. You have still to define those methods:

```
    def bubble(self):
        print('bubble to be implemented')
        return sorted(self.nums)

    def shell(self):
        print('shell to be implemented')
        return sorted(self.nums)

    def quick(self):
        print('quick to be implemented')
        return sorted(self.nums)
```

This is the full code:

```
import random
from tkinter import *

class Sorting(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.function = {0:self.bubble, 1:self.quick, 2:self.shell}
        self.master.title("Sorting")
        self.master.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S )

        #label for sort intro
        self.label1 = Label(self, text="Select Sort", width=25, height=2)
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)

        #Radio buttons for sorts
        self.v = IntVar()
        for indx, button in enumerate(('Bubble', 'Quick', 'Shell')):
            name = "%s Sort" % button
            button = Radiobutton(self, text=name, variable=self.v, value=indx)
            button.grid(row=1, column=indx, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        button.deselect()

        #button to generate number
        self.button4 = Button(self,text='Generate no.',command=self.gen)
        self.button4.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        self.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)

    def create_but2sort(self):
        self.button5 = Button(self, text='start sorting', command=self.sortit)
        self.button5.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        self.rowconfigure(5, weight=1 )
        self.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)

    def gen(self):
        self.nums = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(10)]
        num = ''.join('%4i' % num for num in self.nums)
        self.label2 = Label(self, text=num, width=2, height=2)
        self.label2.grid(row =3, columnspan=10, sticky = W+E+N+S)
        self.create_but2sort()

    def sortit(self):
        function = self.function[self.v.get()]
        result = function()
        num = ''.join('%4i' % num for num in result)
        self.label3 = Label(self, text=num, width=2, height=2)
        self.label3.grid(row=5, columnspan=10, sticky=W+E+N+S )

    def bubble(self):
        print('bubble to be implemented')
        return sorted(self.nums)

    def shell(self):
        print('shell to be implemented')
        return sorted(self.nums)

    def quick(self):
        print('quick to be implemented')
        return sorted(self.nums)

def main():
    Sorting().mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: is it that this code is using same technique for all three sorts to sort...no the algorithms for different sorts...then what is used for sorting these.

Comment: 'shell to be implemented', 'bubble to be implemented', 'quick to be implemented'... ***by you***, I supose...

Comment: ya i know i have to implement those i was just not getting that but now i know ...thanx

Comment: can u check the question on 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205157/i-am-making-a-gui-for-sorting-so-i-want-to-colour-certain-numbers-in-each-step