# A GUI for sorting: how to colour certain numbers in each step of sorting?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

My code for bubble sort is in gui is this:-

```
def bubble(self):
    def bubble_sort ( array ) :
        swap_test = False
        for i in range ( 0, len ( array ) - 1 ):
         for j in range ( 0, len ( array ) - i - 1 ):
          if array[j] > array[j + 1] :
           array[j], array[j + 1] = array[j + 1], array[j]#elegentan way of swap

           swap_test = True
           break
           #if swap_test == False:
        #else:
        #self.create_label()

   #print('bubble to be implemented')
    bubble_sort(self.nums)
    return self.nums
```

So i want to colour elements which are swaped for one step like array[j] and array[j+1] are swapped.

The function used for sorting button and storing it into label is

```
def sortit(self):
    function = self.function[self.v.get()]
    result = function()
    num = ''.join('%4i' % num for num in result)
    self.label3 = Label(self, text=num, width=2, height=2)
    self.label3.grid(row=5, columnspan=10, sticky=W+E+N+S )
```

ok the screen shot is like

[image]

so what i have to do is like after swapping in bubble sort 8 has come to first place so i need to colour the numbers which are being swapped not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to adapt this code to your application.
It uses a `Text` widget with tag's to produce colored text. So, you should substitute your `Label` widgets with `Text`.

```
from Tkinter import *

class Sorting(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Sorting")
        self.master.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky=W+E+N+S )

        nums = [10, 20, 8, 5, 7]       # example of entry
        result = sorted(nums)          # sorted result = [3 ,5 , 8, 10 ,20]

        # the color list holds the items changing position when sortened
        color = [ind for ind, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(nums, result)) if x != y]

        entry_num = ''.join('%4i' % num for num in nums)
        sort_nums = ''.join('%4i' % num for num in result)

        l1 = Label(self,  text="entry", width=25, height=1)
        l1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)

        t_entry = Text(self,  width=25, height=2)
        t_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=N)
        t_entry.insert(END, entry_num)

        l2 = Label(self, text='sorted', width=25, height=1)
        l2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=N)

        t_sorted = Text(self,  width=25, height=2)
        t_sorted.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=N)
        t_sorted.insert(END, sort_nums)

        t_sorted.tag_config('red_tag', foreground='red')

        for pos in color:
            a = '1.%i' % (4 * pos)
            b = '1.%i' % (4 * pos + 4)
            t_sorted.tag_add('red_tag', a, b)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Sorting().mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: ok i have tried this but its like showing only first number in color like in 23 just 2 is blue and also showing it randomly to any number. So what i was thinking to do is to make seperate text box for each element and then colour the particualr that is being swapped. But its showing only last digit so i just applied the for loop in the code above given in question. but its not working

Comment: I can add the rest of my full code for referance ...i tried for loops also but not working..

Comment: in blue? they are red !. you must understand what are you doing before rushing forward. The method in my question is general, non specific, the only limitation, as it is,  is that numbers must be below 999. See why?. If you are coloring the wrong numbers it is not a fault of the Text tagging strategy. Check the structure of your string of numbers and the way tags work and how tag indexes are set and you will discover that you did something wrong. Also you should check how function calls and arguments work. The call to bubble_sort inside bubble in your code is extremely awful and redundant.

Comment: Thnx for telling that ....i put colour as blue . Anyways i don't know much about redundant as i am new to much of coding in so much

Comment: @saira_jane not a software term, just nomal meaning of redundant http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redundant

Answer (score 1):

You have at least a couple of choices. The first is that you create one label widget for each number so that you can color each one separately. The second choice is to use a single text widget. The text widget lets you tag individual character, and apply attributes to those tags. So, for instance, you could have a tag "moved" and set the foreground, background, font, etc for all characters with a "moved" tag.

Think  outside the box a little -- just because a widget is mostly used for input doesn't mean it can't also be used to display data.

Answer (score 0):

is this you want? i hope this can help you.

http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_labels.php

```
self.label3 = Label(self, text=num, width=2, height=2, fg= "blue")
```

Comment: @saira_jane it could be funny. but, how do you think about add two labels. so, put only one character into left label.

Comment: @saira_jane how you think, you make 10 labels. colour each labels. you're able to decide swapped or not by comparing original array and sorted array.